# NSImage not loading macOS Swift

Tags: swift, macos, nsimage

I have this code which successfully shows a system icon in the menu bar when the app is running:

```
statusItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: NSStatusItem.variableLength)
    
    
    if let MenuButton = statusItem?.button{
        
        MenuButton.image = NSImage(systemSymbolName: "gearshape.fill", accessibilityDescription: nil)

        MenuButton.action = #selector(MenuButtonToggle)
        
    }
```

However if I change the code to use a custom image in my `Assets` folder:

```
statusItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: NSStatusItem.variableLength)
    
    
    if let MenuButton = statusItem?.button{
        
        MenuButton.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "icon_2")
        MenuButton.image?.isTemplate = true

        MenuButton.action = #selector(MenuButtonToggle)
        
    }
```

UPDATE:

I have also tried `Bundle(for: type(of: self)).image(forResource: "icon_2")` as an alternative to `imageLiteral`

It doesn't show anything, it's not the image as I have tried loads and I have even tried icons that were used in other projects that I know works for the menubar. What could've gone wrong?

Even used this to debug if the image is loaded or not:

```
if let image_url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "icon", withExtension: "png") {
            print("yes")
        }
```

`yes` does show up

Comment: You should load image from your bundle. Next should be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/60418869/12299030.

Comment: @Asperi Sorry, forgot to mention, I have tried that too

Comment: Then make sure your image is really present in bundle/assets catalog... no miracle here - if it is not loaded then it is not there.

Comment: @Asperi which it is so still very confused to why this doesn't work

Comment: Is `image` `nil`? Is the question about the status item or about loading the image? Please start variable names with a lower case character. I keep thinking `MenuButton` is a class.

Comment: @Willeke no as you can see by the question it is loaded. And sorry I code differently to you, not relevant to the question